# Process to update lookup field in customer portal

Tags: automation

I have been stuck on a problem since Monday, where I am trying to auto-populate a parent case field with the case number of the parent record.[image]

Basically anytime a customer creates a case in the customer portal, he has the possibility to create a case concern if he feels that the support has not answered /fix his issue. So from the case incident he has created, the client can click on a button called case concern and he can fill another form to raise his concern.

What I would like is that, when clicking on the button case concern, the lookup field (called parent case) is automatically filled with the case number of the parent case. I never used a Flow builder but I am told that it can only be done with a Flow. I really don't know what to do. I never used Flow Builder before. I tried to create a screen but I can't even figure out how to integrate it in customer community.

Any help would be so appreciated.
Thank you,
Hermann

Answer (score 0):

Scenario one: I am assuming the case concern is a custom object with a look up field of case?

If this is the case, create an action on case object and assign it to the page layout, the parent case field will be populated automatically. Tried it myself, works for me, it is just the action will the on the chatter publisher.
[image]

Scenario 2: caseconcern is still the case object but with different record type. Same approach, create an action on case but create case record with the record type you want.  Assign it on the page layout, the parent case field will be automatically populated.
[image]

In summary, create an action on case rather than global action.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Really nice of you. The only thing is that I need to create the case concern on the customer portal community. When the customer create a case on community, He has the choice to raise a concern on the case he has created. If he feels that the support team has not done a great job. 
It looks like I will need to create a custom button...

[image]